# Order JPA Entities by related entity property using criteria API

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have 2 legacy entities

```java
public class Owner {
    @Column(name = "board_id")
    private Integer board_id;

    public Integer getBoardId() {
        return board_id;
    }

    public void setBoardId(Integer board_id) {
        this.board_id = board_id;
    } 
}
```

```java
public class Board {
        private String cableId;
        private Integer id;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "board side_seq_name")
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        @Column(name = "cable_id")
        public String getCableId() {
            return cableId;
        }

        public void setCableId(String cableId) {
            this.cableId = cableId;
        } 
}
```

`Owner` and `Board` are connected by `owner.board_id = board.id`.
I have a Criteria API query which returns collection of owners and I need to sort it by `Owner.Board.cableId`.

As I can't put subquery to `orderBy` and I can't change JPA mapping of these entities it doesn't seem easy to me.

Please, give any ideas.

Comment: JPQL "Select owner from Owner owner, Board board where  owner.board_id=board.id order by board.cableId"

Comment: I should have pointed out that JPA 2.1 supports the "ON" clause for joins, but only over non-relationship.  I am not sure if Hibernate extended the support as EclipseLink has, but might be worth trying: http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2012/05/jpql-vs-sql-have-both-with-eclipselink.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't post what you already have you'll have to adapt this to what you need. Something like this

```
CriteriaQuery q = ...
Root<Owner> ownerRoot = q.from(Owner.class);
ownerRoot.setAlias("o");
Root<Board> boardRoot = q.from(Board.class);
boardRoot.setAlias("b");
q.where(qb.eq(ownerRoot.get(Owner_.board_id), boardRoot.get(Board_.id));
q.orderBy(qb.asc(boardRoot.get(Board_.cableId)))
```

Comment: no idea what you mean by "alias". If you want to use "ownerRoot" (which has an alias of 'o') then you use ownerRoot.field just like that example says